# Please help me understand what is going on here

Tags: python, debugging

I am trying to make a scorekeeper for a game of Yahtzee but whenever I put in a variable for `players` it always prints `"I think that's enough."` Please help me understand what is happening here and how I could fix it.

```
#Yahtzee Scorekeeper

if __name__ == "__main__":

    players = raw_input("How many people will be playing?")

    if players == 1:
        print "You can't play Yahtzee by yourself!"
    elif players == 2:
        print "Ready to start with " + str(players) + " players!"
    elif players == 3:
        print "Ready to start with " + str(players) + " players!"
    elif players == 4:
        print "Ready to start with " + str(players) + " players!"
    elif players == 5:
        print "Ready to start with " + str(players) + " players!"
    elif players == 6:
        print "Ready to start with " + str(players) + " players!"
    elif players == 7:
        print "Ready to start with " + str(players) + " players!"
    elif players == 8:
        print "Ready to start with " + str(players) + " players!"
    elif players > 8:
        print "I think that's enough."
```

Comment: Note also that your code is very repetitive; the code for cases 2-7 is identical, so could be trivially simplified.

Answer (score 1):

`raw_input` produces a string, and you're comparing it with a number. In Python 2, the result is as you saw. Try the following:

```
players = int(raw_input("How many people will be playing?"))

if players < 2:
    print "You can't play Yahtzee by yourself!"
elif players > 8:
     print "I think that's enough."
else:
    print "Ready to start with " + str(players) " players!"
```